# How to iframe a web page on a sharepoint site?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, sharepoint-2013, meta-tags, embedding

I've a website and a team services sharepoint site, both authenticating against the same corporate active directory. I want to embed a page from my website in an iframe on a page in my sharepoint site.

**I got the following error message:**

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame. To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame. You can
>   try: Open this page in a new window

I found a stackoverflow answer that says adding the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow"/>
```

in the page that needs to be go within the iframe will do it, and I've tried this, but it does not work. Why is this so? What am I missing/doing wrong here?

When opening in the new window, it works fine, but iframing would be really ideal, so that is the question I have been looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page. Maybe your site responses that way and thats the reason for "the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame" If you got any chance to prevent sending the X-Frame-Option it will work.

Comment: How do I check if my site is sending this response? And how do I prevent it?